# RPI4 and 4G Dongle

Tags: wifi, usb, pi-4, ssh

I setup a 4G connection using below link
viewtopic.php?t=302262

I have a ZTE MF820B dongle.  When my home WIFI is on, I can ssh to the pi. But when I turn off the wifi and use only the ZTE usb dongle, I am not able to ssh.

Only think I know about networking in PING and ROUTE commands.

I have been struggling for a week and am out of ideas and search topics,

Please advice how to connect to my rpi with just my ZTE 4G dongle.

Walton

---

Thank you . This is good advice. I will work on updating my static IP.
my regular ssh on my ethernet of home wifi is over port 22. Doesnt that mean port 22 is also open when the 4g dongle is connected?

mY port 22 is active . I used below link to setup static IP.
circuitbasics.com/how-to-set-up-a-static-ip-on-the-raspberry-pi . I Still cannot connect over the 4g dongle.
Can you tell me what else am I missing . What do I need to check?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn more about how networking works. You can only SSH into your raspberry pi if your USB dongle has a static IP address and have port 22 opened.

One option is to make a reverse proxy that creates a secure tunnel from a public endpoint to a locally running service. You can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), [frp](https://github.com/fatedier/frp) or [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel) like tools for making a reverse proxy.

If you are looking for a managed and easy-to-use solution, use [Dataplicity](https://dataplicity.com) which will allow you to open the terminal of your raspberry pi within their webapp regardless of the network. Dataplicity also make use of reverse proxy behind the scene.

Comment: Thank you . This is good advice. I will work on updating my static IP.

Comment: my regular ssh on my ethernet of home wifi is over port 22. Doesnt that mean port 22 is also open when the 4g dongle is connected?

Comment: mY port 22 is active . I used below link to setup static IP.

Comment: https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-set-up-a-static-ip-on-the-raspberry-pi/ . I Still cannot connect over the 4g dongle.

Comment: Can you tell me what else am I missing . What do I need to check?

Comment: This is late, and I don't know the steps to correct it. The problem is, to me, a misunderstanding of network basics. When you connect using wifi, everything is contained by  your local network. When you use the phone device, the single goes to the nearest cell tower,which is outside your network. I would use ip names. Use dynamic DNS to associate the name an the ip-number of your apartment/house.